# Does a central extension split over some finite index subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

Consider a central extension of groups $\mathcal{E}$ :
$$1\rightarrow A\rightarrow \widetilde{G}\rightarrow G \rightarrow 1$$with $A$ finite cyclic. Does there always exist a finite index subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that the restriction of $\mathcal{E}$ to $H$ becomes trivial?

Comment: I think the following short exact sequence is a counterexample. $$0\to (1/2)\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

Comment: What if you consider the central extension
$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to Q_8 \to \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1,$$
where $Q_8= \{\pm1, \, \pm i, \, \pm j, \, \pm k \}$ is the group of unities of quaternions? It seems to me that all restrictions to the subgroups of $G$ are in this case of the form $$1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2  \to 1.$$

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi, there's no requirement that $H$ shouldn't be trivial in the question.

Comment: @Jason Starr: Oh, right! Not what I had in mind, but it works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Deligne gave a famous example of a central extension
$$
1\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to \widetilde{G}\to G\to 1
$$
such that $G$ is a finite-index subgroup of $PSp(2n,\mathbb{Z})$ but $\widetilde{G}$ is not residually finite. (See, for instance, the references in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48656/is-delignes-central-extension-sofic) MO question.)  But it's easy to see that if the extension were to virtually split then $\widetilde{G}$ would be residually finite.

Comment: The non-residual finiteness of that extension is also the reason that my answer to the following question is wrong: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108211/what-is-the-brauer-group-of-the-moduli-space-of-p-p-abelian-varieties/108231#108231

Comment: Deligne's examples regularly reappear in MathOF; in addition to Jason's answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22814/are-extensions-of-linear-groups-linear/22835, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78341/residually-finite-by-mathbbz-groups-are-residually-finite, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136431/is-hopf-property-a-quasi-isometry-invariant